# How do you pass a variable to a class extension?

Tags: php, oop, class, constructor, scope

The concept of adding a variable to a class's extension is something I am not grasping and could use some help.

This is an example of a class I am extending. It works great but I can't access the $XML variable. I could make $XML a global but I know to avoid doing that.

```
<?php

//Sample XML Object
  $XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
        <data><foo>Bingo!</foo></data>";
  $XML = simplexml_load_string($XML);
// Extend the class
  class myExt extends ENTERPRISE {
      public function HTMLBlock() {
          // Set font
          $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 10);
          $html = '
            <P style="font-weight:normal;">
             This is a test text cell<br />
             Foo is set to '.$XML->foo.'
            </P>
          ';
          // Title
          $this->htmlToBlock(90, '200', $HTML );
       }
  }

  $pdf = new myExt('L', 'Letter', 'Landscape', true, 'UTF-8', false);
?>
```

I have read about constructs. I know I need to add to the parent construct, I still don't undersand where/how I send it the variable. I started with something like this.  (not working)

```
<?php

//Sample XML Object
  $XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
        <data><foo>1</foo></data>";
  $XML = simplexml_load_string($XML);

// Extend the class
  class myExt extends ENTERPRISE {
      function __construct($xmlData) {
        parent::__construct();
      }
      public function HTMLBlock() {
          // Set font
          $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 10);
          $html = '
            <P style="font-weight:normal;">
             This is a test text cell<br />
             Foo is set to '.$XML->foo.'
            </P>
          ';
          // Title
          $this->htmlToBlock(90, '200', $HTML );
       }
  }

  $pdf = new myExt('L', 'Letter', 'Landscape', true, 'UTF-8', false);
?>
```

Do I somehow send the myExt() an additional parameter? Magically at the end? I tried it but didn't work. Maybe something like:

```
$pdf = new myExt('L', 'Letter', 'Landscape', true, 'UTF-8', false,$XML);
```

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: You defined `$XML` in the global scope. So it *is* a global variable. If you want it to be a class variable, you need to define it inside the class, but outside any class functions.

Comment: Can you show us what the `ENTERPRISE` class looks like?

Comment: If you're going to override the superclass constructor method, you probably aught to be passing in all of the arguments it accepts… that won't happen magically.

Comment: Travesty3: The superclass that I was originally trying this on was TCPDF, http://www.tcpdf.org/. I made this example because I was interested in learning. I felt like bring TCPDF into this might distract. You and the others helped me understand more about constructs, thank you.

Comment: Lübnah Thx. I think you agree with rawb below

Comment: I didn't want to define it within the superclass, because it was TCPDF and I didn't want to modify the original "3rd Party" class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really simple example, but if the constructor takes 6 arguments and you wanted to pass it an additional argument you could just override the default constructor.  If you post the ENTERPRISE class I'll update this response!

```
<?php

//Sample XML Object
  $XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
        <data><foo>Bingo!</foo></data>";
  $XML = simplexml_load_string($XML);
// Extend the class
  class myExt extends ENTERPRISE {
      var $XML;
      function __construct($arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4, $arg5, $arg6, $XML)
      {
        parent::__construct($arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4, $arg5, $arg6);
        $this->XML = $XML;
      }
      public function HTMLBlock() {
          // Set font
          $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 10);
          $html = '
            <P style="font-weight:normal;">
             This is a test text cell<br />
             Foo is set to '.$this->XML->foo.'
            </P>
          ';
          // Title
          $this->htmlToBlock(90, '200', $HTML );
       }
  }

  $pdf = new myExt('L', 'Letter', 'Landscape', true, 'UTF-8', false, $XML);
?>
```

Also note that variables in PHP ARE case-sensitive.  So in your HTMLBlock method $html != $HTML.

Comment: Awesome, Makes so much sense. Thx! (the $html vs $HTML was a typo :) )

Comment: Absolutely!  Glad I could help!